# I want idea about delay function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js

Sorry I want to ask about Javascript. I just started studying studying recently.

### index.js

```
import FuncDelay from './FuctionDelay.js'
import Summ from './FuntionSumm.js'
Summ(4)
FuncDelay(1000,Summ(3))
```

---

### FunctionSumm.js

```
export default function Summ(i){
    console.log(i+i)
}
```

---

### FunctionDelay.js

> I have problem in this file.js. This file about delay and callback function but function can't work after delay //cry

```js
export default function asynchronousDelay(delay, callback) {
 setTimeout(function(){ 
  callback
 }, delay);
}
```

> Thank You for Knowledge

Comment: callback would be a function ... you need to **call** the function ... e.g. `callback()` - instead, you are passing the result of calling `Summ(3)` as the callback argument

Comment: as jaromanda pointed out, you can call your function like this : FuncDelay(1000, function(){ Summ(3); }) wich will create a callback function fit your function in it.

Comment: i don't want to fix only Summ(3)... i want to know how i call function  because i try console.log(typeto callback) It show undefined .How callback get function @Neil

Comment: You dont have to fix your summ function. my explaination is too long, i'm gonna paste it in an answer ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As callback is (or must be) a function, you need to call it like this: `callback()`, you forgot the parenthesis.

First when you put a function *with parenthesis* as an argument to a big function, the argument function is executed *before* the big function.

`FuncDelay(1000,Summ(3))` is transformed into `FuncDelay(1000,undefined)` before the functDelay is launched, beacause **undefined is the return value of Summ**. that explains why console.log(typeto callback) shows undefined.

You could get rid of the parenthesis so the argument will be the function and not the return of the function: `FuncDelay(1000,Summ)` but you obviously loose the argument 3 in it, so you need to create a function without any argument that holds your function with an argument. the quick notation is `function(){Summ(3);}`.

Comment: I got it. Thank you